# WCF Service using ASP.NET Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authentication

I am invoking a WCF web service (.NET 4.0) via jQuery $.ajax() from an ASP.NET page. How can I secure the WCF service such that only authenticated ASP.NET users can invoke the service's methods? Do I need to imperatively check the forms authentication cookie manually in each service method, or is there a more declarative approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: Move the .svc files under a "Services" directory (or any directory that will hold the services to be secured) and secure that directory with its own web.config. Configure the location to deny anonymous users:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```