# how to create wcf web service that has username and password in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I want to create `wcf web service` that has `username` and `password` in `asp.net`.so that by providing that username and password, we can consume any web methods.I have already created wcf web service but i want to add username and password in web service.

thanks in advance.

Comment: so basically, you want to authenticate request to your service. [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949792/wcf-service-using-asp-net-forms-authentication) and google more

Comment: but how to set username and password? say for example uname="abc" and password="123" and how to validate whether it is right or wrong?.

Comment: Create a WCF service to authenticate user, create a securitytoken for the user and then pass that security toekn to your methods then validate.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the required steps to achieve what you're asking for:

1) Create a new WCF project using Visual Studio's "new project" interface: you'll end up with two main files: **Service1.svc** (code file) and **IService1.cs** (interface file).

2) Open the **IService1.cs** file and define your method like the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [...]

    // TODO: Add your service operations here

    [OperationContract]
    string GetToken(string userName, string password);
}
```

3) Open the **Service1.cs** file and add the method's implementation in the following way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieve a non-permanent token to be used for any subsequent WS call.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userName">a valid userName</param>
/// <param name="password">the corresponding password</param>
/// <returns>a GUID if authentication succeeds, or string.Empty if something goes wrong</returns>
public string GetToken(string userName, string password)
{
    // TODO: replace the following sample with an actual auth logic
    if (userName == "testUser" && password == "testPassword")
    {
        // Authentication Successful
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // Authentication Failed
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

That's basically it. You can use this technique to retrieve a (expiring & secure) token to use in any subsequent calls - which is the most common behaviour - or implement that username/password strategy within all your methods: that's entirely your call.

To test your new service you can launch your MVC project in *Debug Mode* and use the built-in **WCF Test Tool**: you'll have to enter the sample values specified above (*testUser*, *testPassword*), unless you change them.

For further info regarding this specific topic and additional implementation examples you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/create-soap-web-service-asp-net-wcf-c-sharp-visual-studio-iis-8/) on my blog.